# So how can I project the data with the eigenvectors from LDA?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis, projection

I have data that look like this.

[image]

And my goal is to reduce this 3D dimension into 2D dimension so it might looks like this. Turning the angle so the distance between all classes becomes maximum.

[image]

So therefore I have made a MATLAB-code to use:

```
function [W] = lda(varargin)
  % Check if there is any input
  if(isempty(varargin))
    error('Missing inputs')
  end

  % Get impulse response
  if(length(varargin) >= 1)
    X = varargin{1};
  else
    error('Missing data X')
  end

  % Get the sample time
  if(length(varargin) >= 2)
    y = varargin{2};
  else
    error('Missing class ID y');
  end

  % Get the sample time
  if(length(varargin) >= 3)
    c = varargin{3};
  else
    error('Missing amount of components');
  end

  % Get size of X
  [row, column] = size(X);

  % Create average vector mu_X = mean(X, 2)
    mu_X = mean(X, 2);

    % Count classes
    amount_of_classes = y(end) + 1;

    % Create scatter matrices Sw and Sb
    Sw = zeros(row, row);
    Sb = zeros(row, row);

    % How many samples of each class
    samples_of_each_class = zeros(1, amount_of_classes);
    for i = 1:column
      samples_of_each_class(y(i) + 1) = samples_of_each_class(y(i) + 1) + 1; % Remove +1 if you are using C
    end

    % Iterate all classes
    shift = 1;
    for i = 1:amount_of_classes
      % Get samples of each class
      samples_of_class = samples_of_each_class(i);

      % Copy a class to Xi from X
      Xi = X(:, shift:shift+samples_of_class - 1);

      % Shift
      shift = shift + samples_of_class;

      % Get average of Xi
      mu_Xi = mean(Xi, 2);

      % Center Xi
      Xi = Xi - mu_Xi;

      % Copy Xi and transpose Xi to XiT and turn XiT into transpose
      XiT = Xi';

      % Create XiXiT = Xi*Xi'
      XiXiT = Xi*XiT;

      % Add to Sw scatter matrix
      Sw = Sw + XiXiT;

      % Calculate difference
      diff = mu_Xi - mu_X;

      % Borrow this matrix and do XiXiT = diff*diff'
      XiXiT = diff*diff';

      % Add to Sb scatter matrix - Important to multiply XiXiT with samples of class
      Sb = Sb + XiXiT*samples_of_class;
    end

    % Use cholesky decomposition to solve generalized eigenvalue problem Ax = lambda*B*v
  Sw = Sw + eye(size(Sw));
    L = chol(Sw, 'lower');
    Y = linsolve(L, Sb);
    Z = Y*inv(L');
    [V, D] = eig(Z);

    % Sort eigenvectors descending by eigenvalue
    [D, idx] = sort(diag(D), 1, 'descend');
    V = V(:,idx);

    % Get components W
    W = V(:, 1:c);
end
```

And a working example

```
% Data for the first class
x1 = 2*randn(50, 1);
y1 = 50 + 5*randn(50, 1);
z1 = (1:50)';

% Data for the second class
x2 = 5*randn(50, 1);
y2 = -4 + 2*randn(50, 1);
z2 = (100:-1:51)';

% Data for the third class
x3 = 15 + 3*randn(50, 1);
y3 = 50 + 2*randn(50, 1);
z3 = (-50:-1)';

% Create the data matrix
X = [x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3];

% Create class ID, indexing from zero
y = [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2];

% How many dimension 
c = 2;

% Plot original data
close all
scatter3(X(:, 1), X(:, 2), X(:, 3), 'r')
hold on
scatter3(X(:, 4), X(:, 5), X(:, 6), 'g')
hold on
scatter3(X(:, 7), X(:, 8), X(:, 9), 'b')

% Do LDA - Now what?
W = lda(X, y, c);
```

The $W$ matrix contains a lot of eigenvectors. What I need to do is to multiply $W$ with $X$, but the problem is that It's not possible. I can make the $W$ into transpose, but still, I don't think that's the right method to use.

So how can I project the data with the eigenvectors from LDA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm late here, but this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/563678-how-to-interpret-the-coefficients-of-the-lda-function-fitcdiscr-for-dimensionality-reduction?requestedDomain=) may be helpful to you if you're still exploring this.

Modified from Alexander Jamieson's answer there:

```
Mdl = fitcdiscr(X,y)
[W, LAMBDA] = eig(Mdl.BetweenSigma, Mdl.Sigma) %Must be in the right order! 
lambda = diag(LAMBDA);
[lambda, SortOrder] = sort(lambda, 'descend')
W = W(:, SortOrder);
Y = X*W;
```

You may be looking instead for X*W.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of link-only answers, due to link rot. Can you edit to include a full citation & a summary of the information at the link, in case it goes dead?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).